# 31st date showing invalid date when using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am finding the difference between 2 dates in years, but when I select the **31st** date it shows an invalid date so the difference is `NaN`.

When I use other dates it shows the correct result.

```js
const selectedValue = moment('31-8-2022');
const today = moment();
const yearDiff = today.diff(selectedValue, "year");
console.log(yearDiff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When running sample code you provided, a deprecation warning is raised:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or
> ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not
> reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date
> formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major
> release. Please refer to
> http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

By inputing the date in ISO format, the code works:

```js
const selectValue = moment('2022-08-31'); // 2022-08-31 instead of 31-8-2022
const today = moment();
const yearDiff = today.diff(selectValue, "year");
console.log(yearDiff);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use `'DD-MM-YYYY'` in momentjs you get invalid date format.

```js
const selectedValue = moment('30-08-2022').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(selectedValue)
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

In order to make it valid date, you'll add `'DD-MM-YYYY'` in the `moment` second paramater after the date and format it.

```js
const selectedValue = moment('30-08-2022','DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(selectedValue)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

In instance you really have to use `'DD-MM-YYYY'` in your code without the worry of depreciation warning. You could do this

```js
const selectedValue = moment('30-08-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(selectedValue)
const today = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(today)
const yearDiff = moment(today, 'DD-MM-YYYY').diff(moment(selectedValue, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'years');
console.log(yearDiff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```